# MVC Create Controller - DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Estoy usando MVC/Entity Framework, el error que me está saliendo es el siguiente:***The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed***

Sí se crea el registro, pero me sale ese error cada vez que guardo el registro. Antes, (ayer) no me sucedía, pero hoy empezó a hacer eso y no he modificado nada. Cualquier otra info, hacerme saber.

> Clase Projecto

```
public class ProjectValidation
    {
      [Remote("ValidacionExistenciaMCP", "Projects", ErrorMessage = "MCP ESTÁ EN USO. Utilizar otro.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El número MCP es Requerido.")]
    public string NumberMCP { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Somthing")]
    public int EngineerID { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Somthing")]
    public int SiteLocationID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Somthing.")]
    public string nameProject { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Somthing")]
    public string Ptype { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Somthing Somthing")]
    public int Pyear { get; set; }

    public string Plink { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [GridColumn(Format = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fecha Recibido es Requerida.")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fr { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fecha Completado es Requerida.")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fc { get; set; }

    public byte[] MCPcontent { get; set; }
    public string Proj { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller Create (Controlador Crear)

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.EngineerID = new SelectList(db.Engineers.OrderBy(b => b.eName), "EngineerID", "eName");
            ViewBag.SiteLocationID = new SelectList(db.SiteLocations.OrderBy(b => b.nameSL), "SiteLocationID", "nameSL");
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult Create(Project mcpc, HttpPostedFileBase file, [Bind(Include = "ProjectID,NumberMCP,EngineerID,SiteLocationID,nameProject,Ptype,Pyear,Plink, Fr, Fc, MCPcontent, Proj, ContentType")] Project project)
        {
            try
            {
                if (seg.ValidaAcceso(Session["AppCode"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["UsrRol"]), "Crear"))
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid && file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                            string ds = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.Length - 3);
                            string p = string.Empty;
                            p = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
                            file.SaveAs(p + file.FileName);

                            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                                byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                                using (db)
                                {

                                    mcpc.Proj = file.FileName;
                                    mcpc.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                                    mcpc.MCPcontent = buffer;
                                    db.Projects.Add(mcpc);
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                }

                            }

                            ViewBag.EngineerID = new SelectList(db.Engineers.OrderBy(b => b.eName), "EngineerID", "eName", project.EngineerID);
                            ViewBag.SiteLocationID = new SelectList(db.SiteLocations.OrderBy(b => b.nameSL), "SiteLocationID", "nameSL", project.SiteLocationID);


                            #region logueando accion
                            Seguridad.CreateLog("Project", Seguridad.SerializeToJson(project), Seguridad.GetEventoIDByName("Crear"), project.ProjectID, Session["UsrName"].ToString(), Session["rIP"].ToString());
                            #endregion

                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        } 
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["Message"] = "No se elegió ningún archivo.";
                        return RedirectToAction("Create");
                    }

                             }

                 else
                    {
                        return seg.NotAccess();

                    }

            }

            catch  {

                return View("Index");

            }

            }
```

> **ERROR TRACE**
>
> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been
>   disposed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The operation
>   cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because
>   the DbContext has been disposed.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +1067    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +25
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +21    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +59    System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector) +61
>
>   PMPDI.Controllers.ProjectsController.Create(Project mcpc,
>   HttpPostedFileBase file, Project project) in
>   \\nttappsweb0009\PMPDI\Controllers\ProjectsController.cs:145
>
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +240
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +35
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +67
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +385    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +69
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +607    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134

Comment: coloca tu pregunta en español para ayudarte mas facíl

Comment: Me sale 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed when i create a new record' Pero, aun saliendome ese error se crea el registro. No sé porque me sale ese error si me estaba funcionando bien anteriormente.

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Comment: Sería interesante ver cómo creas tu DbContext (asumo que es la variable db). Cómo lo creas? Si lo estás pasando mediante IoC entonces lo más probable es que estás reutilizando la instancia y eso puede provocar que se haga dispose junto al controller.

Comment: Mil gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando recibes un archivo, tienes una condicion si da true entonces el contexto de base de datos entrara en un block `using` lo que provocara que la conexion se cierre:

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    //...
    using (db)
    {
        //...
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Ahora bien, la conexion de base de datos también se utiliza mas debajo y cuando quieres consultar, ya la conexion estara cerrada.

Elimina el `using` o declara en `using` al principio del metodo para que la cierre cuando el metodo termine de ejecutarse:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Project mcpc, HttpPostedFileBase file, [Bind(Include = "ProjectID,NumberMCP,EngineerID,SiteLocationID,nameProject,Ptype,Pyear,Plink, Fr, Fc, MCPcontent, Proj, ContentType")] Project project)
{
    try
    {
        // lo declaramos al inicio del metodo para que se cierre cuando termine de ejecutarse el metodo y no antes
        using(db)
        {

            if (seg.ValidaAcceso(Session["AppCode"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["UsrRol"]), "Crear"))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid && file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                        string ds = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.Length - 3);
                        string p = string.Empty;
                        p = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
                        file.SaveAs(p + file.FileName);

                        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                            mcpc.Proj = file.FileName;
                            mcpc.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                            mcpc.MCPcontent = buffer;
                            db.Projects.Add(mcpc);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }

                        ViewBag.EngineerID = new SelectList(db.Engineers.OrderBy(b => b.eName).ToList(), "EngineerID", "eName", project.EngineerID);
                        ViewBag.SiteLocationID = new SelectList(db.SiteLocations.OrderBy(b => b.nameSL).ToList(), "SiteLocationID", "nameSL", project.SiteLocationID);


                        #region logueando accion
                        Seguridad.CreateLog("Project", Seguridad.SerializeToJson(project), Seguridad.GetEventoIDByName("Crear"), project.ProjectID, Session["UsrName"].ToString(), Session["rIP"].ToString());
                        #endregion

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    } 
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "No se elegió ningún archivo.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }

                         }

                else
                {
                    return seg.NotAccess();

                }
        }

    }
    catch {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Einer, te sigo.

Comment: No creo que el bloque `using` tenga sentido ya que `db` parece ser una variable global. O se crea un `db` local, y allí sí se puede usar el `using`, o no se usa el `using` en absoluto. De lo contrario, simplemente se está posponiendo el error a mas tarde.

Comment: @sstan tiene sentido y mucho, ya que la conexion a base de datos sera cerrada inmediatamente y no habrá que esperar a que el GC la reclame, algo que tomara tiempo, y no llenara el pool de conexiones del servidor SQL.

Comment: La conexión existe, aparentemente lanzaba eso porque se creaba e inmediatamente te replicaba que no se podía hacer un duplicado. Al menos lo entiendo así. I'm new a this.

Comment: Agregando a lo ya recomendado por @sstan me dirijo al OP para aclarar que MVC es un patrón de diseño que va implementado en la capa de presentación mas no es una arquitectura te sugiero separes responsabilidades y persistas contra la base de datos en una capa de acceso a datos así la implementación de tu código quede mas limpia y mas prolija.